# Round to certain values

Tags: rounding

For a program I write I need some optimal values. I calculated them using Mathematica and I get something like this:

```
{2375, 2556, 2758, 2974, 3201, 3677, 4173, 5068}
```

Since my program only accepts specific values like ...

```
{2000, 2800, 3600, 4200, 5500}
```

... I will need to round my calculated values to those. That means that every calculated value should be replaced by the closest accepted number.

This is only an example. I calculated more than a hundred values and dont want to round them by myself. How can I use Mathematica to achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is one way

```
data = {2375, 2556, 2758, 2974, 3201, 3677, 4173, 5068};
vals = {2000, 2800, 3600, 4200, 5500};

Nearest[vals, #] & /@ data // Flatten
(* {2000, 2800, 2800, 2800, 3600, 3600, 4200, 5500} *)
```

Comment: Easy. Thank you!